# XMLHTTP --- ERR_CONNECTION_RESET

Tags: arduino, xmlhttprequest, esp32

I'm working on a greenhouse project(ESP32). The following code is supposed to write data to the web server(sensors) and read the switch status for manual controls of the devices.
I've managed to get it working but console keeps giving ERR: CONNECTION RESET 
when calling the request setLED.
The switches itself work fine, but since I've never worked XMLHttp, I think I've made a mistake somewhere.

```
VM385:1 GET http://192.168.0.104/setLED?lamp=false&pump=false&fan=false net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET
```

```
const char MAIN_page[] PROGMEM = R"=====(
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<style>
.card{
    max-width: 400px;
     min-height: 250px;
     background: #02b875;
     padding: 30px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
     color: #FFF;
     margin:20px;
     box-shadow: 0px 2px 18px -4px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
}

.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input { 
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}

/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

</style>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
<meta charset='urf-8'>
</head>
<body>

<div class="card">
  <h4>The ESP32 Update web page without refresh</h4><br>
  <h1>Temperature: <span id="temp">0</span> C</h1><br>
  <h1>Humidity: <span id="humidity">0</span> %</h1><br>
  <h1>Water moisture: <span id="watermoisture">0</span> %</h1><br>
  LAMP
  <br>
<label class="switch">
  <input class="controls" id="lamp"type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label><br>
<br>
PUMP
<br>
<label class="switch">
  <input class="controls"  id="pump"type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label><br>
<br>
FAN
<br>
<label class="switch">
  <input class="controls" id="fan"type="checkbox">
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label><br>
</div>
<script>

setInterval(function() {
  // Call a function repetatively with 2 Second interval
  getData();
}, 2000); //2000mSeconds update rate

function getData() {
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      var data = this.responseText.split("\t");
      document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = data[0];
      document.getElementById("humidity").innerHTML = data[1];
      document.getElementById("watermoisture").innerHTML = data[2];
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "readADC", true);
  xhttp.send();
  var states = [false,false,false];
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  var controls = document.getElementsByClassName("controls");
  for(var i=0;i<controls.length;i++){
    if(controls[i].checked) states[i]=true;
    if(!controls[i].checked) states[i]=false;
  }
  console.log(states);
  var arguments = "lamp=" + states[0] + "&pump=" + states[1] + "&fan=" + states[2];
  xhr.open("GET", "/setLED?" + arguments, true);
  xhr.send();
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
)=====";
```

```
/*
 * ESP32 AJAX Demo
 * Updates and Gets data from webpage without page refresh
 * https://circuits4you.com
 */
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WebServer.h>
#include <DHT.h>

#include "index.h"  //Web page header file

WebServer server(80);

#define DHTPIN 25
#define DHTTYPE DHT22
DHT dht(DHTPIN, DHTTYPE);

//Enter your SSID and PASSWORD
const char* ssid = "";
const char* password = "";

//===============================================================
// This routine is executed when you open its IP in browser
//===============================================================
void handleRoot() {
 server.send(200, "text/html", MAIN_page); //Send web page
}

void handleADC() {
 String adcValue;
 float a = dht.readHumidity();
 float b = dht.readTemperature();
 String humidity = String(a);
 String temperature = String(b);
 adcValue += "10";
 adcValue += "\t";
 adcValue += "25";
 adcValue += "\t";
 adcValue += "30";
 server.send(200, "text/plain", adcValue); //Send ADC value only to client ajax request
}

 void handleLED() {

String lampstate = server.arg("lamp");
String pumpstate = server.arg("pump");
String fanstate = server.arg("fan");

Serial.println(lampstate);
Serial.println(pumpstate);
Serial.println(fanstate);
}


//===============================================================
// Setup
//===============================================================

void setup(void){
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Booting Sketch...");

  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); //Connectto your wifi
  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

  Serial.println("Connecting to ");
  Serial.print(ssid);

  //Wait for WiFi to connect
  while(WiFi.waitForConnectResult() != WL_CONNECTED){      
      Serial.print(".");
    }

  //If connection successful show IP address in serial monitor
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to ");
  Serial.println(ssid);
  Serial.print("IP address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());  //IP address assigned to your ESP
//----------------------------------------------------------------

  server.on("/", handleRoot);   
  server.on("/readADC", handleADC);
  server.on("/setLED", handleLED);

  server.begin();                  //Start server
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
  dht.begin();
}

//===============================================================
// This routine is executed when you open its IP in browser
//===============================================================
void loop(void){
  server.handleClient();
  delay(1);
}
```

Comment: You setup two `XmlHttpRequest`, `xhttp` and `xhr`, on the second request `xhr` you don't have the callback function setup `xhr.onreadystatechange`.

Comment: BTW, if you are using ESP32, you can use its built-in SPIFFS lightweight file system to store html, css, javascript in the ESP32 flash and serve its as static content. I have a [blog](https://www.e-tinkers.com/2019/11/build-an-esp32-web-server-and-ir-remote/) post in which I have an example on how to use it.

Comment: `handleLED` doesn't send a response `server.send(200, ...`